# Getting type error while iterating through columns to make API request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/michaelbryantds/tornadoes/) where I am iterating through four columns (date, slat, slon, time) to make an API request from this API https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/timeline-weather-api/. I have drawn a weighted sample of 250 tornadoes (so I won't surpass the 1000 request/day limit).

The goal is to use those three datapoints to append the temperature, humidity, and pressure data to each tornado.

The problem I am having is I am getting

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

when I try to make a simple "for" loop to cycle through and print the responses before I even try to code in the portion to append it to the DF. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
df = Sample_df

Sample_df.slat.astype('float')
Sample_df.slon.astype('float')

for (tornado,lon) in df.iterrows():
    date = lon['date']
    lat = lon['slat']
    lon = lon['slon']
    t = lon['time']
    
    apikey = 'MY_API_KEY'
    url = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/{},{}/{}T{}?key={}".format(lat,lon,date,time,apikey)
    response = requests.get(url)  
    response_dict = response.json()
    print(response_dict)
```

Comment: What does the `Sample_df` do?

Comment: Sample_df is sampled df of 250 tornadoes. It is what I am iterating through.

Answer (score 1):

You have redefined `lon` in cycle to a float `lon = lon['slon']`.
Choose another name for this variable.

Also `time` is not defined, but `t` is.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue that you've used reassigned the variable `lon` before you finished extracting all the data:

```py
for (tornado,lon) in df.iterrows():
    date = lon['date']
    lat = lon['slat']
    lon = lon['slon']  # Overwrites the variable lon with a float value
    t = lon['time']  # Attempts to access the old value of lon
```

You can fix this by giving the variable a different name:

```py
for (tornado,data) in df.iterrows():
    date = data['date']
    lat = data['slat']
    lon = data['slon']
    t = data['time']
```